# MVVM DataTemplate and non-empty view model constructor

Tags: c#, mvvm, datatemplate

I have the below DataTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
        <views:MyView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The thing is, my view model has a constructor that takes parameters which are automatically injected by the container (unity).  In order for the DataTemplate to work though, MyViewModel needs to have a paramaterless constructor.

Is there any other way I can inject the appropriate values into my view model if I am using a DataTemplate to create it?

Comment: Did you ever develop a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Views should be creating ViewModels.

ViewModels should be creating other ViewModels, and the View simply defines how to draw the ViewModel.

For example, a `ParentViewModel` might have a property called `ChildViewModel`. The `ParentView` will contain a ContentControl which has its Content bound to `ChildViewModel`, and a DataTemplate would be used to tell the application to draw `ChildViewModel` as a `ChildView`.

With that being said, how is your View currently creating your ViewModel? You could always add DependencyProperties to your View and build your ViewModel in the View's loaded event using these properties.

Comment: Thanks Rachel.  Before I moved to using DataTemplates, the view models were injected into the view via the constructor (using unity).

Comment: @Rachel can you provide an example of how to use the `DataTemplate` to tell the application to draw `ChildViewModel` as a `ChildView`. Is this possible with constructor-based dependency injection?

Comment: @Thomas Sure, you just need to add an implicit DataTemplate in your XAML, like the question here has. I also have another example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14881037/302677), or just google around for "WPF Implicit DataTemplate" and you should find plenty of other resources about it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using an MVVM framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), and take a ViewModel first approach.