# WPF Getting a pointer from a template object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I have a XAML snippet that looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ns:MyObject}">
    <Grid>
        /// Stuff

    </Grid>
    <GridView x:Name="MyGrid" />
</DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ns:MyObject x:Name="MyLovelyObject" />
```

Now, I'd like to have a pointer to "MyGrid". However, due to the intrinsic design of WPF, it's not possible to easily access "MyGrid" at a code level. So, I am looking for an alternative. The following is something I want to do but cannot quite work out the syntax (note: GridView is a public attrribute of MyObject):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ns:MyObject}">
    <Grid>
        /// Stuff

    </Grid>
    <GridView Binding="{Path=GridView}" />

</DataTemplate>
<GridView x:Key="GridViewTemplate">
    /// Lots of stuff
</GridView>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ns:MyObject x:Name="MyLovelyObject" GridView="{Binding GridViewTemplate}" />
```

Anyhow, that obviously doesn't work out. Basically it appears I have two goals for the XAML:
1. Create MyObject using a DataTemplate
2. Initialize MyObject.GridView using another DataTemplate (Note: GridView is a GUI object)

Any inputs on this?

Thanks.

Comment: `Any inputs on this?` Yes: Do NOT manipulate WPF UI Elements from code. Much less if they're inside a Template. What do you want that for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing in your code, but I'll give this my best shot.

First off, DataTemplates only exist to tell WPF how to draw an object. They are not an actual UI object that will get rendered on their own.

There are two types of DataTemplates: Implicit and Explicit.

Implicit DataTemplates do not have an `x:Key` field, and are used automatically when WPF goes to render an object of the specified DataType.

For example, you have `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ns:MyObject}">` in your first code block, so WPF will use this template anytime it needs to render an object of type `ns:MyObject`

Explicit DataTemplates have an `x:Key` defined for them, and must be explicitly defined in the XAML where you want to use them. For example, if you had `<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomNsObjectTemplate">`, then you could apply it to your object like `<ns:MyObject Template="{StaticResource CustomNsObjectTemplate}" />`

And Second, if the `GridView` object is a UI object, you should use a `ContentControl` to display it instead of trying to use another `GridView`. Something like

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding GridView}" />
```

Now I suspect what you're trying to do is use a custom `GridView` object in your DataTemplate by passing in the `GridView` in your `UserControl.Resources` to the `GridView` property of your `MyObject` class.

If that's the case, you'll want to create your `GridView` UI object in your `<UserControl.Resources>`, and pass it to your object using a `{Static Resource }` binding in your `MyObject` definition.

You'll also want to switch how you display the `GridView` in your `DataTemplate` from a `GridView` to a `ContentControl`, and you'll probably want to wrap both your `Grid` and `GridView` in a single parent control, like a `StackPanel` or you'll get an exception.

So your end code might look something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ns:MyObject}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                /// Stuff
            </Grid>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=GridView}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <GridView x:Key="MyCustomGridView">
        /// Lots of stuff
    </GridView>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ns:MyObject GridView="{StaticResource MyCustomGridView}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel. This is exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately, I can't upvote you because I've been downvoted to oblivion by others so much that I don't even have the "privilege" to upvote. :)

Comment: @user1836155 That's fine, glad I was able to help :)

Comment: By the way, out of curiosity: Why does GridView in MyObject not have to be explicitly declared as a dependency object in the code to work?

Comment: @user1836155 You are creating an instance of `MyObject` in your XAML, and setting it's `GridView` property equal to your custom GridView defined in `<UserControl.Resources>`. It's basically the same as saying `var obj = new MyObject(); obj.GridView = Resources.MyCustomGridView;`, except you're writing that with XAML instead of C#. A `DependencyProperty` on the other hand is a type of property that can be set with a binding, which tells the object that it needs to look up the value of the property in a different location when its referenced.

Comment: @user1836155  For example, if you had wanted to bind the `GridView `property to a value that existed in another location instead of setting it to a `StaticResource`, you would need to make it a `DependencyProperty`. This way, it would it would be able to look up it's value in a different location instead of simply reading the value on the object like a normal property would. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Thank you Rachel. That is most helpful!